# thread_local variables initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, thread-local

I know this is a very basic question but I wasn't able to find a simple answer.

I'm writing a program in which I need some variables to be `thread_local`. From my understanding this means that those variables are "like global variables" but each thread will have its own copy.

I've put these variables in a dedicated namespace called `utils` inside a header file called `Utilities.hpp` in this way:

```
// Utilities.hpp
namespace utils {
    extern thread_local int var1;
    extern thread_local int var2;
    extern thread_local std::vector<double> vect1;
}
```

I've used the `extern` keyword in order to avoid multiple declaration.
Anyway when I try to initialize these variables in the `.cpp` file inside the same `namespace` like this:

```
// Utilities.cpp
namespace utils {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    std::vector<double> vect1;
}
```

I get this error:

```
Non-thread-local declaration of 'var1' follows thread-local declaration
```

And the same for every other variable `var2` and `vect1`.

I've tried to initialize them as a normal static variable of a class at the beginning of my program in the `main.cpp` file like this:

```
int utils::var1;
int utils::var2;
std::vector<double> utils::vect1;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    return 0;
}
```

but the error I get is always the same.

I don't understand how to initialize this kind of variables, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Specifically, let's see a `.cpp` file.

Comment: You need `thread_local` in both the declarations *and* the definitions.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you! If you want to post it as an answer I'll set this question as solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the comments...

The declarations and definitions must match.  Hence the `thread_local` storage qualifier needs to be in both.  So you need...

```
// Utilities.hpp
namespace utils {
  extern thread_local int var1;
  extern thread_local int var2;
  extern thread_local std::vector<double> vect1;
}
```

and...

```
// main.cpp
thread_local int utils::var1;
thread_local int utils::var2;
thread_local std::vector<double> utils::vect1;
```